# My customers' Google Play in-app purchases are stuck in the 'pending' state, going on 2+ days

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-checkout, android-pay

I have an Android app with premium features that can be activated by an in-app purchase. If I look at the transaction list in Google Wallet's merchant view, I see that normally customer purchases within the past 6 hours are "pending" (yellow circle), then change to "green" (charged successfully).

However, since July 5 (two days ago), all purchases have remained in the Pending state. The charges are not being cleared and no money is being deposited in my merchant account, even though customers are continuing to buy the product.

Is anyone else seeing this? What's going on?

Comment: I'm seeing this as well.

Comment: Hi, we have the same issue with in-app purchases... we use the inappV3

Comment: Same problem here with normal purchase of apps from Play Store.

Comment: Regarding those who have flagged this as off-topic: I posted here because Google Wallet's [help link](https://support.google.com/payments/?hl=en) contains a link to Google's [developer forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/in-app-payments), and the help forum's [last post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/in-app-payments/4j6n950ukzM) is from a Google employee saying they're moving all Wallet technical support to Stack Overflow. So I posted to Stack Overflow, only to have the question marked as "off-topic". Where do I fill out my 27B/6?

Comment: @uscjeremy That post specifically states questions **about the API**, not general support questions. It is off topic for SO...

Comment: Mine just started turning green again..